# Creating an HTML link that leads to a page with value of java string

Tags: java, html, string, href

I've tried to create an additional link to an existing report page that will display content of a string. However, when clicking on the link, it leads to a grey page with the message:
It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
This is a snippet of the hyperlink I'm trying to create which is saved as a string in Java:

```java
//myString is the string containg the value I want to display on the new page
String myString = "Value to be displaayed on new page";
String newLink = "<a href= '" + myString + "'>Click here to see the value</a>";
```

This is how the link is on my html page, when clicking on it, it is not presenting myString value.

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: first try to add a random string literal such as `google.com` and see if it works.

Comment: This one also didn't work: "<a href= 'google.com'>Click here to see the value</a>"

Comment: what do you get when you inspect the link in dev tools?

Comment: I see href="google.com", but when I put the cursor on the google.com link I see that the path is: file:/// and path to my java automation path and then the google.com. So the problem is because of it?

Comment: yeah probably. add `https://` at the beginning and it'll probably work.

Comment: At the beginning of where?

Comment: `https://google.com`, or `'https://' + myString`

Comment: Ok, now on the inspect it shows http:// and the value itself, but not showing on the actual new page.